# How to solve " Some vertex names in edge list are not listed in vertex data frame" in plotting Social Network Analysis

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking, sna

I have made my edge file and nodes :

```
edges<-structure(list(source = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "e", 
"e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e"), target = c("CONCEPT-OF-SELF", 
"ENERGY", "SLEEP-SYMPTOMS", "ATTENTION", "COGNITIVE-ABILITY-THING", 
"COGNITIVE-CONTROL", "COGNITIVE-IMPAIRMENT-THING", "CONCEPT-OF-SELF", 
"DELUSIONS", "DEMENTIA", "EXECUTIVE-SYSMPTOMS", "LANGUAGE-ABILITY-THING", 
"LEARNED-COGNITIVE-ABILITY", "LOSS-OF-CONSCIOSNESS", "MEMORY-LOSS", 
"NEGETIVE-MOOD-AFFECTIVITY", "SUICIDAL-IDEATION", "COPE", "INTERPERSONAL-TRUMA", 
"INTERPERSONAL", "POOT-PYSCHOSOCAL-FUNCTION", "SOCIAL-PROCESS", 
"ENERGY", "DEMENTIA", "IMPUSIVITY", "LANGUAGE-ABILITY-THING", 
"LOSS-OF-CONSCIOSNESS", "RECOGNITION-THING", "NEGETIVE-MOOD-AFFECTIVITY", 
"APPROACH-MOTIVATION", "PERSONAL-MANNER-THING", "EXECUTIVE-SYMPTOMS", 
"DELUSIONS", "DEMENTIA", "EXECUTIVE-SYSMPTOMS", "LANGUAGE-ABILITY-THING", 
"LEARNED-COGNITIVE-ABILITY", "DEMENTIA", "IMPUSIVITY", "LANGUAGE-ABILITY-THING", 
"LOSS-OF-CONSCIOSNESS"), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), weight = c(7L, 37L, 13L, 85L, 9L, 36L, 4L, 5L, 19L, 1L, 
10L, 1L, 2L, 36L, 161L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 56L, 6L, 1L, 10L, 
70L, 56L, 18L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 20L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 
12L, 19L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -41L
))

nodes<-structure(list(ID = 1:31, name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "CONCEPT-OF-SELF", 
"ENERGY", "SLEEP-SYMPTOMS", "ATTENTION", "COGNITIVE-ABILITY-THING", 
"COGNITIVE-CONTROL", "COGNITIVE-IMPAIRMENT-THING", "DELUSIONS", 
"DEMENTIA", "EXECUTIVE-SYSMPTOMS", "LANGUAGE-ABILITY-THING", 
"LEARNED-COGNITIVE-ABILITY", "LOSS-OF-CONSCIOSNESS", "MEMORY-LOSS", 
"NEGETIVE-MOOD-AFFECTIVITY", "SUICIDAL-IDEATION", "COPE", "INTERPERSONAL-TRUMA", 
"INTERPERSONAL", "POOT-PYSCHOSOCAL-FUNCTION", "SOCIAL-PROCESS", 
"IMPUSIVITY", "RECOGNITION-THING", "APPROACH-MOTIVATION", "PERSONAL-MANNER-THING", 
"EXECUTIVE-SYMPTOMS")), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used this code from "igraph" package to plot my social network :

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(d=edges, vertices=nodes, directed=FALSE)
```

However, I got the following error while I used all the sources and target in my vertices file:

```
Error in graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, vertices = nodes, directed = FALSE) : 
  Some vertex names in edge list are not listed in vertex data frame
```

Could you please help me how to identify values are not listed vertex data frame as my main data set is bigger than sample.

Comment: I think `igraph` is assuming your node names are in the `ID` column.  If I remove it, I don't get the error: `g <- graph_from_data_frame(d=edges, vertices=nodes %>% dplyr::select(-ID), directed=FALSE)` seems to work.  I checked with `edges %>% dplyr::anti_join(nodes, by = c('source' = 'name'))` and `edges %>% dplyr::anti_join(nodes, by = c('target' = 'name'))`, and all your source and target names exist in `nodes$name`

Comment: @Hobo is correct. The documentation states, "If vertices is not NULL, then it must be a data frame giving vertex metadata. The first column of vertices is assumed to contain symbolic vertex names, this will be added to the graphs as the ‘name’ vertex attribute." https://igraph.org/r/doc/graph_from_data_frame.html

Comment: Or select the column containing the vertex names:  `g <- graph_from_data_frame(d=edges, vertices=nodes$name, directed=FALSE)`.

Comment: Use `setdiff(x, y)` to find the difference between x and y. In this example `setdiff(c(edges$source, edges$target), nodes$name)`, which gives `character(0)`.

Comment: Thank you all. The problem was related to the ID column.